# HLS.js, data is loading, but no video

Tags: http-live-streaming, hls.js

I'm trying to use [hls.js](https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js) to embed a video from a live stream in a website. I can play the video for instance in VLC or ffplay. `ffmpeg -i http://192.168.11.10` gives some information about the stream:

```
Input #0, mpegts, from 'http://192.168.11.10':
  Duration: N/A, start: 40921.528689, bitrate: N/A
  Program 1
  Stream #0:0[0x44]: Video: h264 (Baseline) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(progressive), 1280x720, 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc
```

When I try to load the video directly using hls, I can see that data is being downloaded continuously, but no video is shown. The video control shows a spinning circle, pressing the play button does nothing. The `Hls.Events.MANIFEST_PARSED` event is never triggered.

```html
<video id="test_video" controls autoplay></video>
```

```js
var hls = new Hls({debug: true});
hls.on(Hls.Events.MEDIA_ATTACHED, function () {
    console.log(`HLS attached to video element ${hls.media.id}`);

    hls.loadSource('http://192.168.11.10');
    hls.on(Hls.Events.MANIFEST_PARSED, function (event, data) {
        console.log('Manifest loaded, found ' + data.levels.length + ' quality level');
    });
});
hls.attachMedia(document.getElementById('test_video'));
```

I also tried this using an intermediate `.m3u8` file. I'm not sure if I have the format correct, though:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXTINF:68400,MyVideo
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:68400
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=4000000,CODECS="avc1.42e02a",RESOLUTION=1280x720
http://192.168.11.10
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

and

```js
hls.loadSource('test.m3u8');
```

Now `Hls.Events.MANIFEST_PARSED` is triggered, and I get some more information from hls in the browser's console. However, although there is still a continuous data stream coming in from the video server, there is no video either. No `Hls.Events.ERROR` event is triggered.

```
HLS attached to video element test_video
hls.js:1 [log] > stopLoad
hls.js:1 [log] > [subtitle-stream-controller]: IDLE->STOPPED
hls.js:1 [log] > loadSource:http://localhost/easp/test.m3u8
hls.js:1 [log] > [stream-controller]: Trigger BUFFER_RESET
hls.js:1 [log] > [level-controller]: manifest loaded, 1 level(s) found, first bitrate: 0
hls.js:1 [log] > 1 bufferCodec event(s) expected
(index):42 Manifest loaded, found 1 quality level
hls.js:1 [log] > startLoad(-1)
hls.js:1 [log] > [level-controller]: switching to level 0 from -1
hls.js:1 [log] > [stream-controller]: STOPPED->IDLE
hls.js:1 [log] > [subtitle-stream-controller]: STOPPED->IDLE
hls.js:1 [log] > [stream-controller]: Level 0 loaded [0,0], cc [0, 0] duration:68400
hls.js:1 [log] > [buffer-controller]: Updating Media Source duration to 68400.000
hls.js:1 [log] > [stream-controller]: Loading fragment 0 cc: 0 of [0-0] level: 0, target: 0
hls.js:1 [log] > [stream-controller]: IDLE->FRAG_LOADING
```

My question is: How can I fix this? Or maybe more in general, how can I get more information about what is going wrong?

(Note: I tried on Edge, Chrome and Firefox)

Comment: facing the same issue. any update @Berend

Comment: @neevany Our video provider switched to a different stream type (HLS, IIRC), that fixed it for us. I believe they also needed to set some CORS HTTP headers on the responses to GET and OPTION requests, but if your video is on the same host, that shouldn't be necessary of course

Comment: I got the same problem with HLS. About 50% of the channels of my provider can't play video :( Only audio works. No errors. In network-console video-parts are loaded, but not displayed. VLC or "M3U IPTV" app on Samsung TV works fine.